How to calculate the current and voltages of this Sziklai pair?

Im new to Sziklai pairs and could not find any information on how to do calculations for this case. Im trying to do DC calculations and the info i have : +IN and -IN are for AC source, the +VE and -VE are 15V. I want to know the currents of both pnp and npn transistors emitters, bases and collectors but since I need the base currents known (which i dont) to calculate the collector currents, I'm stuck.
Additional question:
Are the resistors R3 and R4 meant as a voltage divider to make sure the voltage difference between emitter and base of Q2 is 0.7V? Or is R3 a feedback for the Sziklai pair in which case I'm not sure what R4 is for?
The original souce : https://www.sound-au.com/project66.htm
I would appreciate any help with the calculations and explanations.

A Sziklai pair acts pretty much like a transistor of "the input transistor type" with unusually high current gain and saturation voltage. Imagine more current to the base of Q2 than through R3 and look at R2&R4. Use a simulator to look at potentials and currents.

In this care about base current. Notice that the Q1 base is at 0V thus the Q1 emitter will be Vbe larger around 0.6..0.7V Therefore I_R2 = (15V - 0.65V)/4.7k = 3mA. The Q1 will be Ic_Q1 = 0.65V/680R = 1mA and from there we know that Ic_Q2 = 3mA - 1mA = 2mA

@G36 How do you know to use 0.65V voltage drop accross 680 ohm resistor to calculate the current Ic_Q1 if the voltage on the other side of the 680 ohm resistor is unknown apart from the authors note of -8.3V? Doesnt this mean that not all of the 0.65V will drop accross this resistor?

We do not know the exact value of a Vbe voltage, but we know it will be between 0.6V and 0.7V. The exact value is unknown. However, from our experience, we also know that Vbe voltage will be around 0.65V for IC = 1mA (for small-signal BJT). Also, notice that R3 is connected in parallel to the Q2 base-emitter junction. This means that the voltage drop across R3 must be equal to Vbe as well.  Because they are connected in parallel, therefor I_R3 = Vbe/R3 = 1mA.  And this -8.3V is a voltage between Q2 emitter and gnd. (V_EQ2 = 3mA * 2.2k - 15V = 6.6V - 15V = -8.4V).

@G36 I think I understood it now, but just to clarify... do you assume Ib_Q2 as close to 0, so that the emitter and collector current of Q1 are around the same?

Yes, I'm assuming that the transistor's beta is large, therefore I can assume that Ic = Ie.

Thank you, just one last question. What is the point of R4 od 2.2k ohms? Is it there as part of a voltage divider with R3 or does it have a different purpose and R3 is just feedback to improve turn-off speed?

R3 to improve the turn-off speed and set the bias current. R2 is just like an ordinary Rc resistor in a common emitter amplifier.

What I dont understand is why R4 is connected to both emitter of Q2 and collector of Q1

I made a mistake R2 is an emitter resistor and R4 is a collector resistor.  Why, because the Sziklai pair is a complementary version (using PNP and NPN) of a Darlington stage. https://sound-au.com/articles/cmpd-vs-darl.htm

@G36 Thank you so much, this was very helpful!
